# How far can you scatter light using a prism?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

If I were to scatter light how far do you think it would disperse? What prism most effectively scatters light?

Comment: The refraction index will depend on the wavelength.

Comment: The problem with your question and reason for the answers you got (simply: what exactly do you want to know?) is your strange wording. The dispersed light beam makes up an angle, narrow or wide, but never "far". The thing of interest is "dispersion", which is a quality of the prism material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prism *refracts* light, it doesn't scatter it. I'm confused about what you're asking.

If you're asking about the *dispersion* that occurs when (for example) white light passes through a prism, that depends on the material of the prism, and it's a fairly involved topic. But the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_%28optics%29) article points out some of the physics behind it.

If you're asking about literally how far the light refracted by a prism travels, that again depends greatly on the material surrounding the prism, but you could have a look at the [attenuation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient) (also extinction coefficient).

Comment: Sorry I meant refract, and I'm asking about how far the different type of lights could disperse. Thanks

Comment: Note Georg's comment above. "Dispersion" has a special meaning in physics. If you were to asking something like "How much is light dispersed?", you'd be asking "How wide is the angle subtended by the rainbow as it exits the prism?" It is another question if you ask how $far$ the light travels once it leaves the prism.

Answer (score 2):

Prisms don't scatter light, they refract it. The amount of refraction depends on the material's index of refraction, or the change in the speed of light in that substance (assuming that the prism is surrounded by normal air). The highest index of refraction, as far as I am aware, belongs to diamond, so a diamond prism would cause the sharpest bending of light (unless there's a higher IoR out there that I don't know about).

Comment: In the visible range, diamond has one of the highest refraction index, but there are other materials with even higher indexes (TiO2 for instance)

Comment: Okay. My knowledge of refraction comes from an old book on optics (hence my assumption that the light would be visible) and paying attention in high school *cough*. I never even knew TiO2 was transparent...